# Apache virtualhost - Mac OSX 10.7.3

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost

After upgrading to Lion, all my virtualhosts stopped working. They redirect to "It works" main apache page on my device for some weird reason.

Example:

/etc/hosts:
`127.0.0.1  myhost.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/testproj/"
    ServerName myhost.com

    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/testproj/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/testproj-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/testproj-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Did anyone else face the same issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: Might be worth cross-posting to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this snippet part of `httpd.conf`?  Or is it in a separate file?  If the latter, are you certain that the appropriate `Include` directives are still in place?

Comment: @larsks Yes i am pretty sure the include directive is in place..

Comment: @alex Why, its obviously a server question, not some generic, "why isn't iDevice X connecting with iMusicNoteOnBlueCircle?" question.

Comment: The virtual host you are providing would be the same as the default (port 80); which virtual host **isn't** working?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like two apache's were working together. the homebew one and the macport one... removing macport apache fixed the issue... seems like i was modifying the apache config that wasn't the one working on port 80